# how to sort list.files() in correct date order?

Tags: r, sorting, date

Using normal `list.files()` in the working directory return the file list but the numeric order is messed up.

```
f <- list.files(pattern="*.nc")
f
# [1] "te1971-1.nc"  "te1971-10.nc" "te1971-11.nc" "te1971-12.nc"
# [5] "te1971-2.nc"  "te1971-3.nc"  "te1971-4.nc"  "te1971-5.nc" 
# [9] "te1971-6.nc"  "te1971-7.nc"  "te1971-8.nc"  "te1971-9.nc"
```

where the number after `"-"` describes the month number.

I used the following to try to sort it

```
myFiles <- paste("te", i, "-", c(1:12), ".nc", sep = "")
mixedsort(myFiles)
```

it returns ordered files but in reverse:

```
[1] "te1971-12.nc" "te1971-11.nc" "tev1971-10.nc" "te1971-9.nc" 
[5] "te1971-8.nc"  "te1971-7.nc"  "te1971-6.nc"  "te1971-5.nc" 
[9] "te1971-4.nc"  "te1971-3.nc"  "te1971-2.nc"  "te1971-1.nc"
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Add `decreasing=TRUE` inside `mixedsort()` 
Not sure why but it worked for me. 
Also `stringr` has `str_sort(myFiles, numeric = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the values get alphabetically sorted.

You could `gsub` out years and months as groups `(.)` and add `"-1"` as first day of the month to the yield, coerce it `as.Date` and `order` by that.

```
x[order(as.Date(gsub('.*(\\d{4})-(\\d{,2}).*', '\\1-\\2-1', x)))]
# [1] "te1971-1.nc"  "te1971-2.nc"  "te1971-3.nc"  "te1971-4.nc"  "te1971-5.nc" 
# [6] "te1971-6.nc"  "te1971-7.nc"  "te1971-8.nc"  "te1971-9.nc"  "te1971-10.nc"
# [11] "te1971-11.nc" "te1971-12.nc"
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- c("te1971-1.nc", "te1971-10.nc", "te1971-11.nc", "te1971-12.nc", 
       "te1971-2.nc", "te1971-3.nc", "te1971-4.nc", "te1971-5.nc", "te1971-6.nc", 
       "te1971-7.nc", "te1971-8.nc", "te1971-9.nc")
```